# Adding encoders to Nomad 4WD

Tags: ros

i have a nomad 4wd rover kit but i saw that motors doesn't have encoders. But to use odometry with ros i need it. I cannot found any suggestion on google search, so i ask here if someone could route me to some solutions.

thanks

Edit: Sorry, i forget to add the kit link: https://www.servocity.com/nomad

Comment: Please edit your question to add a link to the specific kit you're using. I did eventually find it, but it took a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [Actobotics Nomad chassis kit](https://www.servocity.com/nomad), I assume.

I did this with another Actobotics kit. Buy two extra motors of the same type with encoders, and use these for the rear motors. Get the ones with the same gearbox.

[These are the motors that come with the kit.](https://www.servocity.com/motors-actuators/gear-motors/heavy-duty-gear-motors/premium-planetary-gear-motors)

[Here are the original motors.](https://www.servocity.com/motors-actuators/gear-motors/heavy-duty-gear-motors/premium-planetary-gear-motors)

[Here are the ones with encoders.](https://www.servocity.com/motors-actuators/gear-motors/heavy-duty-gear-motors/premium-planetary-gear-motors-with-encoders)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the fast reply, i see that the motors are the same, so is it possible to add encoder to existing motors without waste money to buy new motors with encoder?

Comment: It would be difficult to do it nicely. The normal motors don't seem to have a shaft coming out the back. The rear shaft is directly from the motors which gets you more resolution than the shaft after the gearbox. You only need two of the motors (one right, one left) to have encoders, though all four would be nice.